# jQuery Validate plugin - how to show all errors by an event (pressing a button)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, submit

I'd like to show all validation errors by pressing button (not submit button).

```
somebutton.button().click(function () { //not submit button
     //some code here
     //to show up all validation messages
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What validation library are you using? I presumed you mean validate a form? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Toddish, see description of [`[jquery-validate]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate?sort=faq) tag.

Comment: @Sparky Cheers, I'll look for that in the future :)

Answer (score 5):

> **Quote:**  *"I'd like to show all validation errors by pressing button (not submit button)."*

See below for proper solution along with a working demo...

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="whatever" />
</form>

<button id="yourbutton">click to show errors</button>
```

**jQuery:**

[Use `.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) to *initialize* the plugin:

```
$('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin
    // your options and rules
});
```

[Then use `.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to *test* the form's validity:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function () {
    $('#myform').valid(); // run a validity test on the form (shows any errors)
});
```

**> > Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/8FdVm/**

Demo #2 (with a submit button):  http://jsfiddle.net/3uZrt/

---

Alternatively, you can use the *boolean* returned by `.valid()` to do other stuff too:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function () {
    if ($('#myform').valid()) { // also instantly shows any errors
        // run code if the form tests valid
    } else {
        // run code if the form tests invalid
    }
});
```

Demo #3 (boolean):  http://jsfiddle.net/qd5AQ/